# Can one trust/ist it worth waiting for a mysql query that exceeds "Read Timeout"?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, timeout

Basically everything is in the title.
I have a query based on updates and join of tables which takes very long. I am able to cut it in slices but I would prefer to run it once. It takes a very long time, way longer than the "Read Timout" limit so tha tI got an error message in PhpMyAdmin.
On the other hand I see on the server that the transaction (processes of the database in PhpMyAdmin) is still running.
So here comes my question: czan I trust this transaction? Is it worth waiting for the transaction to terminate or is it wise to interrupt it and find a way to decompose the task so tha tit can take lesse tiem?
Many thanks for the answers.

I attach the query for thoses interested:

```
insert into `rt_air_rail_5_23` 
( `dNomOri`, `dNomDes`,`dNomConurbOri`, `dNomConurbDes`, 
`dHdep`, `dHarr`, 
`dTemps`, `dTveh`, `dTmap`, 
`dTatt`, `dTatt1`, `dPole`, `dTexte`, `dType`, 
`tpsDispo`, `aType`, 
`aHdep`, `aHarr`, 
`aTemps`, `aTveh`, `aTmap`, 
`aTatt`, `atatt1`, `aPole`, `aTexte`,  `dId`, `aId`,
`dori`, `ddes`, `aori`, `ades`,  `dconurbOri`, `dconurbDes`,`dmodeOri`, `dmodeDes`, `anomOri`, `anomDes`, orix, oriy, desx, desy)
SELECT 
d6.NomOri, d6.NomDes, d6.nomConurbOri, d6.nomConurbDes,
SEC_TO_TIME((d6.`heureo`)*60) dHdep, SEC_TO_TIME((d6.heured)*60) dHarr,     SEC_TO_TIME((d6.temps)*60) dTemps, SEC_TO_TIME((d6.tveh)*60) dTveh, d6.tmap dTmap, d6.tatt dTatt, d6.tatt1 dTatt1, d6.pole dPole, d6.`texte` dTexte, d6.Type dType, 
SEC_TO_TIME((a21.`heureo`-d6.`heured`)*60) tpsDispo, a21.Type aType,
SEC_TO_TIME((a21.`heureo`)*60) aHdep, SEC_TO_TIME((a21.heured)*60) aHarr, SEC_TO_TIME((a21.temps)*60) aTemps, SEC_TO_TIME((a21.tveh)*60) aTveh, a21.tmap aTmap, a21.tatt aTatt, a21.tatt1 atatt1, a21.pole aPole, a21.`texte` aTexte,  d6.id dId,   a21.id aId,
d6.ori, d6.des, a21.ori, a21.des, d6.conurbOri, d6.conurbDes, d6.modeOri, d6.modeDes,a21.NomOri, a21.NomDes, d6.dx, d6.dy, d6.ax, d6.ay
FROM `rt_air_rail_d_5h45` d6
join `rt_air_rail_a_22h15` a21
on 
(
   (
     (d6.type=101  and a21.type=101) and                           #cas fer fer
     (d6.`conurbOri`=a21.`conurbDes` and d6.`conurbDes`=a21.`conurbOri`)
   ) 
or (
    (d6.type=201 and  a21.type=102)  and                      #cas air fer
    (d6.`Ori`=a21.`Des` and d6.`conurbDes`=a21.`conurbOri`)
   ) 
or (
    (d6.type=102  and a21.type=201) and                             #cas fer air
    (d6.`conurbOri`=a21.`conurbDes` and d6.`Des`=a21.`Ori`)
  )
or ( 
     (d6.type=202 and  a21.type=202) and                            #cas air air
     (d6.`Ori`=a21.`Des` and d6.`Des`=a21.`Ori`)
  ) 
)
where d6.`conurbOri` <> d6.`conurbDes` ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, most probably not in the most elegant way, by appending four select queries with the "union" instruction. This allowed me to pass all the queries into one single instruction and avoid the "time out" problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to kill the process and try an EXPLAIN SELECT (followed by the rest of your SELECT statement) to see why it's slow (probably missing indexes).

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do following your indications, but unfortunately I have been fighting with indexes for hours and hours with no success so far: this is the result of the command EXPLAIN EXTENDED:      id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  filtered  Extra
1  SIMPLE  a21  ALL  ori,des,conurbOri,conurbDes  NULL  NULL  NULL  132554  100.00  Using where
1  SIMPLE  d6  ALL  des,conurbDes,desori  NULL  NULL  NULL  148520  100.00  Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2A)

Comment: by the way, replying to my own question, it happen that even very long (almost an hour) the results are correct when the proces ended, they are equal to the query exectuted in four slices without timeout; but then I am left with a query to be optimised, which is anothe issue